# SystemJS: Application died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, webpack, single-page-application, systemjs

So, we are in the process of setting up a larger application consisting of several React apps. We are using the single-SPA framework and got the [single-spa-portal-example](https://github.com/me-12/single-spa-portal-example) running.

In the example, SystemJS is included directly from `portal/libs` folder. We changed it to be managed via npm and after running `npm update` we are now using SystemJS v. 3.0.2.

The `loadApp` function defined in `/portal/src/helper.js` makes use of `SystemJS.import()` (changed that to `import()` with the same result).

Webpack is configured to serve the `singleSpaEntry.js` file for example at the URL `http://localhost:9001/app1/src/singleSpaEntry.js` (for app1) as an AMD module. It does so fine, I can open that file directly in the browser.

When opening the portal app at `localhost:9000` I can also verify that the `loadApp`function is running. However, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught app1: Application 'app1' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE:
>   Cannot find module '/app1/src/singleSpaEntry.js'
>       at http://localhost:9000/main.js:12500:11

I get this error for every sub app, I have tried multiple webpack configurations but I assume this issue is either related to SystemJS itself or to the way the module should be declared in singleSpaEntry.js.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is:

1. open up the root config project in the browser (localhost:9000)
2. enable dev tools (`localStorage.setItem('devtools', true)`)
3. reload
4. open the orange-looking button from the bottom-right of screen
5. get your micro front-end app name from its pkg.json file (@your_directory/micro_front_end_name)
6. create an override and add your micro front-end name there
7. for the override link, paste the URL that your micro frontend up and running (http://localhost:8080 for example)
8. boom, now you have it there!

btw, if you are still seeing some error regarding pkgs like react, react router, vue or any high level things like them, you need to create an override for them as well and the link for them will come from a cdn like cloudflare with desired version.

Answer (score 0):

I had some headache with this problem today, and I was able to solve it just by adding the .default on the configuration of SystemJS.import(), I followed this [repo](https://github.com/Beej126/single-spa-systemjs-cra2.1-ts-no-eject/blob/master/main/src/helpers/microSpa.ts), take a look at line 21, where he puts the `.default` in the end, this was enough to make my applications work just fine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How is that helper used? I dont see any webpack config or any other configs that connects the helper anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing this line in the root's `index.ejs`:

```
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "@example/root-config": "//localhost:9000/example-root-config.js",
    "@example/application1": "//localhost:8080/example-application1.js"  <!-- Missing this line-->
  }
}
```